# MS Teams Bot: Sometimes finding no members

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I've got an ms teams bot app.  It has an endpoint called /api/members.json

```js
server.get("/api/members.json", async (_req, res) => {
  const members = []
  for await (const member of getMembers()) {
    const { account } = member
    const { id, name } = account
    members.push({
      id,
      name,
    })
  }

  res.json({
    members: members,
  })
})
```

here's the implementation of getMembers():

```js
async function* getMembers() {
  const pageSize = 100
  let continuationToken = undefined

  do {
    const pagedData = await notificationApp.notification.getPagedInstallations(
      pageSize,
      continuationToken
    )
    const installations = pagedData.data
    continuationToken = pagedData.continuationToken

    for (const target of installations) {
      const members = await target.getPagedMembers(pageSize, continuationToken)
      yield* members.data
    }
  } while (continuationToken)
}
```

My goal here is to install this bot for the full team and get all of the members of the team from an external api (actually a tab app).

I'm using vscode to build and run.  Yet when I run from an empty state, the members endpoint returns no members (if I install it on a channel/team level).

Sometimes, if I add it as a personal app, I'll only get one member (myself).

When I then add it again to the channel, I get all of the members, as I would expect.

Any idea why this would happen and/or how to get around it?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using Cloud Adapter or BotFrameworkAdapter?

Comment: @RamFattah Not sure?  Following the guide at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/build-notification-bot?tabs=teamstoolkitcodespaces

Answer (score 1):

If you install the bot in personal scope, you will get only one member details and if you install it in Teams's channel you will get all the channel members and it is by design behavior.

You can refer this sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-conversation/csharp/Bots/TeamsConversationBot.cs#L46

Comment: Thanks.  I've noticed that often if I install the bot in the channel scope I get all of the members.  Then at some point, this stops and I get no members.

Comment: I later have to reinstall the bot in the personal scope to just see one member, and then if I later install it in the channel scope I see all members again.  Maybe the bot is installed multiple times?

Comment: One possible reason for this behavior is that the bot might be installed multiple times in different scopes. When a bot is installed in multiple scopes (e.g., channel scope and personal scope), it can lead to unexpected behavior and inconsistencies in accessing the members.

Comment: Oh thank you!  So should I limit it to scope 'teams' (aka "scopes": ["team"], in manifest.json)?

Comment: I'm also seeing this with getMembers(): FetchError: request to http://localhost:56150/_connector/v3/conversations/personal-chat-id/activities/<a uuid> failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED

Comment: This error is because of network issues. Please try to add retry logic and check once.

Comment: I updated all configuration files from a clean state and no longer see the ECONNECTIONRefused.

Comment: Wanted to share this screencast: https://www.loom.com/share/fe7c74ded4544aaea8935ebb87085aca.  So turns out installations is an empty array - any idea why that would be?

Comment: Interestingly, after I message the bot, I can now see myself: https://www.loom.com/share/17464a23bd7440549093d434b8c830ba

Comment: Also the bot is _only_ installed in the teams context

Comment: Hello @smtlaissezfaire as it is an intermittent issue, we are not able to repro this as well.